PKCS#10 with Null Signature according to MS-WCCE
I am trying to create a sample Certificate Request Using CMS and CMC Request Formats with Null Signature as described in [MS-WCCE]: Windows Client Certificate Enrollment Protocol. According to the specification the request should consists the following:

With the PKCS#10 with Null Signature, as described here:

Is there a way how to obtain such PKCS#10 request with Null Signature from some Windows tools or programatically?
I was trying to use BouncyCastle with the following method, however, submitting such request always results in

Active Directory Certificate Services could not process request 976 due to an error: Invalid Signature. 0x80090006 (-2146893818 NTE_BAD_SIGNATURE). Additional information: Error Verifying Request Signature or Signing Certificate.

My code looks like this:
X500Name subject = new X500Name("CN=Test");
AlgorithmIdentifier subjectPublicAlg = new AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.rsaEncryption);

SubjectPublicKeyInfo spki = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded());

// we need to create hash of the certification request info that will be used as signature
CertificationRequestInfo certificationRequestInfo = new CertificationRequestInfo(subject, spki, ats);
// sha256 object identifier
AlgorithmIdentifier algOid = new AlgorithmIdentifier(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1")); // sha256
// signature will be sha256 digest of certificationRequestInfo ASN.1 encoded
byte[] signature = digest(certificationRequestInfo.getEncoded());

// build certification request as PKCS#10 with Null Signature
CertificationRequest certificationRequest = new CertificationRequest(
        subject,
        subjectPublicAlg,
        new DERBitString(spki),
        ats,
        algOid,
        new DERBitString(signature)
);

TaggedAttribute[] taggedAttributes = new TaggedAttribute[0];
TaggedRequest[] taggedRequests = new TaggedRequest[] { taggedRequest };
TaggedContentInfo[] taggedContentInfos = new TaggedContentInfo[0];
OtherMsg[] otherMsgs = new OtherMsg[0];

PKIData pkiData = new PKIData(
        taggedAttributes,
        taggedRequests,
        taggedContentInfos,
        otherMsgs
);

ASN1ObjectIdentifier pkiDataOid = new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.12.2");
CMSProcessableByteArray cmsProcessableByteArray = new CMSProcessableByteArray(pkiDataOid, pkiData.getEncoded());

CMSSignedData cmsSignedData = Utils.createCmsSignedDataWithKeyAndCert(cmsProcessableByteArray, keyPair, cert, true);

Any advice what can be wrong? The logs and event on ADCS are not very helpfull, and I am not even sure that the PKCS#10 with Null Signature is supported in my ADCS or it needs to be updated or patched somehow.
